# Разные ответы от деления на положитльные и отрицательные числа (python)

Tags: python-3.5, деление

Здравствуйте,

```
print(divmod(7, 4))
```

Ответ: (1, 3)

```
print(divmod(7, -4))
```

Ответ: (-2, -1)

```
print(divmod(-7, -4))
```

Ответ: (1, -3)

Как все это считается??

Comment: Что help(divmod) говорит?

Comment: Во втором случаи идет округлению к большему. Наверное это вас запутало.